# Pull out constant from Laplace operator with rescale factor

Tags: derivatives, constants

Say I have a 2 dimensional cartesian laplace operator for a function

$\Delta f = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial X^2} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial Y^2}$

Part of the exercise is to scale the coordinates with a constant ie $X = kx, Y = ky$

How do you pull out k from the laplace operator? My suggestion was:

$\Delta f = k(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2})$

However this was clearly wrong, and I have a hard time finding information on how this would work. Thankful for any explanation!

(this is to simplify the expression that the laplace operator is in, but it's unnecessary info for my question)

Comment: Do multivariable chain rule. (Really, single variable will work, but this is good practice for when you change coordinate systems to polar or others.)

Comment: I am still a bit confused. When I do it, I get k^2 out of the derivative, while the solutions say it is supposed to be 1/(k^2). I do not see how that is sadly...